# Copy from Dataframe Source to SQL Server Destination using JDBC

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, dataframe, databricks

I'm working in a Python environment in Databricks.  I imagine that there should be several ways to copy a dataframe to a table in SQL Server.  Here are two code samples that I'm testing.

```
# Saving data to a JDBC source
jdbcDF.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .save()


jdbcDF2.write \
    .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename",
          properties={"user": "username", "password": "password"})
```

In both cases, I get an error on the very first line, and it reads:

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I'm reading through the documentation here.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

I have a dataframe setup the way I need it to be (source).  I have a table in SQL Server that has all matching field names and varchar data types (destination).  I just need to copy from the source to the destination.  How can I do that?  TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just according to your error information, I think your `jdbcDF` object in the sample code should not be [`pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame), may be just [`pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame).

So the error you got is `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'write'`. If my judgement is right, you need to convert the pandas dataframe to the PySpark dataframe via the code below to fix it.

```
spark_jdbcDF = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_jdbcDF)
```

Then to write it to SQL Server.

Meanwhile, if your destination is SQL Server, the `jdbc` info in the code is for `postgresql`, not for SQL Server.

So you need to install the jdbc driver of MS SQL Server first, as the figures below.

Fig 1. Click `Search Packages` link in the tab `Maven` of the `Install New` dialog of `Libraries` tab.
[image]

Fig 2. Switch to `Maven central` to search `com.microsoft.sqlserver` for jdbc.
[image]

Then, to change the jdbc url for MS SQL Server like the below one and you can refer to the offical document [`Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using Java`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://yourserver.database.windows.net:1433;
```

Otherwise, you also can directly write a pandas dataframe to SQL Server table via the function [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) with a [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html) connection for MS SQL Server.

Comment: any idea which is faster? If writing to the same DB is there any advantage to using `df.write.jdbc` over `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`?